# MS CRM 2015 importing parse limitation on 4998 records

Tags: parsing, import, dynamics-crm-2015

I imported my csv file that contain 17000 records to CRM 2013 without any problem, 
but when I want import it to CRM 2015 it failed after parsed 4998 records and don't continue.

Comment: then split your file

Comment: What plugins do you have running on those records?  I have run into several issues with files that size when i've had plugins running in the background.

Comment: I don't run any plugin on them but there is one workflow on them that also run on crm 2013.

Comment: what is the error on the import job?  or is there an error on each subsequent row?  Do the 4998 parsed rows also get imported or do they just stay in parsed status?  Is the workflow set to run synchronously?  If so, consider deactivating the workflow, then running it on-demand after the import has completed.  (There could be some kind of time out issue)